# How to preserve dates from xts time series data after forecasting

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, xts

Please consider this small dataset:

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)

data <- data.frame(idDate = c("12-12-2012", "13-12-2012", "14-12-2012", "16-12-2012", "19-12-2012"), score= c(110, 120, 130, 200, 180))
date <- as.Date(as.character(data$idDate), "%d-%m-%Y")
score <- as.numeric(data$score)

myxts <- xts(score, date)
autoplot(myxts)
```

So far the date (Index) along the x axis is preserved but as soon as I call forecast, the date along my x axis gets converted to integer. see below:

```
d.arima <- auto.arima(myxts)
d.forecast <- forecast(d.arima, level = c(95), h = 3)
d.forecast
autoplot(d.forecast)
```

questions: 
How can the index from `myxts` be kept? 
Is there a way to tell `forecast` or `auto.arima` to preserve the date (Index) from `myxts`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want `forecast` to also  tell you the date it is forecasting?

Comment: Yes, I want the source data and the forecasted data along the the x axis on date format instead of integers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are working in two different time systems: `xts` is irregular (uses dates with no required periodicity) while `forecast` / `ts` system is regular (uses evenly spaced numeric sequence). We get around this by creating a future date sequence that can be mapped to the forecast.

Here's a detailed solution. The `forecast` and `xts` packages are used for recreating the forecast. The `timekit` package is use for creating future dates. The `ggplot2` package is for plotting.

The key to your problem is creating the future dates. Note that what you have is irregularly spaced. `tk_make_future_timeseries()` uses matches the periodicity of your input time index. If this is not correct, you can remove and insert dates as necessary using `skip_values` and `insert_values`, respectively.

```r
library(forecast)
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(timekit)

# Recreate xts data, d.arima and d.forecast
data <- data.frame(idDate = c("12-12-2012", "13-12-2012", "14-12-2012", "16-12-2012", 
                              "19-12-2012"), 
                   score= c(110, 120, 130, 200, 180))
date <- as.Date(as.character(data$idDate), "%d-%m-%Y")
score <- as.numeric(data$score)
myxts <- xts(score, date)
d.arima <- auto.arima(myxts)
d.forecast <- forecast(d.arima, level = c(95), h = 3)

# Extract index
idx <- tk_index(myxts)
idx
#> [1] "2012-12-12" "2012-12-13" "2012-12-14" "2012-12-16" "2012-12-19"

# Make future index
idx_future <- tk_make_future_timeseries(idx, n_future = 3)
idx_future
#> [1] "2012-12-20" "2012-12-22" "2012-12-23"

# Build xts object from forecast
myts_future <- cbind(y = d.forecast$mean, y.lo = d.forecast$lower, y.hi = d.forecast$upper)
myxts_future <- xts(myts_future, idx_future)
myxts_future
#>              y     y.lo     y.hi
#> 2012-12-20 148 70.33991 225.6601
#> 2012-12-22 148 70.33991 225.6601
#> 2012-12-23 148 70.33991 225.6601

# Format original xts object
myxts_reformatted <- cbind(y = myxts, y.lo = NA, y.hi = NA)
myxts_final <- rbind(myxts_reformatted, myxts_future)

# Plot forecast - Note ggplot uses data frames, tk_tbl() converts to df
tk_tbl(myxts_final) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = index, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y.lo, ymax = y.hi), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Matt; this is a very creative solution. This is what I am after. Thank you. Ironically I just read about the timekit package.

Comment: Originally wanted to use ts() and auto.arima but was not able to retain the date column either. Using your method was it even necessary to use xts() here?

Comment: It's not actually necessary to use `xts` with the timekit setup. You can go directly from `tbl` (data frame) to `ts` then to `auto.arima()`. Also, this is a consistent problem that I run into all the time, and as a result I'm working on a more intuitive solution that leverages the timekit package (more to come!).

Comment: The `sweep` package is in development but can be tested for you purpose. The vignette shows the workflow which goes something like this: 1) start with date-based data frame, 2) coerce to ts using `tk_ts()`, 3) model using `auto.arima` or whichever model you like, 4) forecast using `forecast`, and 5) use `sw_sweep(timekit_idx = TRUE)` to return the forecast as data frame with dates. `devtools::install_github("business-science/sweep")`

Comment: I will check it out. I do fish forecasting for different watershed often and having the date along the x axis is more intuitive. Thanks for sharing.