# Converting Forecast class representation of dates to actual calendar dates

Tags: r, date-format, arima, forecast

Good day,

I am building an auto.arima forecast in R. I was able to complete the forecast successfully, however the results is not displaying the date.

Forecast result:

[The Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i1PY.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCYG8.png)

So if you look at the x-axis, you see here it displays the years in periods.I would like to be able to export this data with actual dates

I use

library("tseries")

library("forecast")

library("xts")

**The code**:

```
Pulsedata$date <- as.Date(Pulsedata$date,format = "%d-%b-%y")
PD_ts <- msts(Pulsedata$Call_volume, start = c(2016, 01), end = c(2018, 
365), seasonal.periods=c(365))
DPD_ts <- decompose(PD_ts, "multiplicative")
AA <- auto.arima(ts(PD_ts,frequency=365),D=1)
Myforecast <- forecast(AA,h=365)
plot(Myforecast)
```

I have tried:

Anydate

sweep

as.date

lubridate

setDT

Comment: `as.Date(time(Myforecast))`?

Comment: that did not work either. I was able to find the solution in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478893/how-to-preserve-dates-from-xts-time-series-data-after-forecasting